# best way to input a complex data structure into a gui (eclipse)

Tags: json, templates, user-interface, input, eclipse-plugin

i have a exlipse plugin which can call a service and the user has to sepcifie the values of the parameters for it. these parameters may be complex.
i was thinking what would be the best way to provide input for them.
I know about the structure of the data type so something like a json template where the user would just fill out the values came to my mind.
But maybe there is a better solution and/or related work on that subject.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question is kind of vague, but if I understand you correctly, the common way to do what you need, in eclipse plugin and RCP development, is to define a model and bind data to it using [JFace Data Binding](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFace_Data_Binding). Lars Vogel wrote a good [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDataBinding/article.html) on this subject.

Comment: hi Sandman. i looked briefly in to it but i don't think i can use these because my data structure may be recursive. i was thinking about a tree as another solution, where your put the values in the leaves.

Comment: @hbral I really can't offer any better advice than this based on what I know about your project, but I don't see why your model couldn't be a tree-like structure. Then again, as I said, I don't know much about your project, so I may be wrong. If you want to, you could edit your question so it's a bit more informative, maybe we could come up with some solution.